# Reboot during software RAID1 rebuild?

Tags: mac-osx, software-raid

I have two disks in a software RAID1 in OSX 1.6

One of them failed, and I'm rebuilding it now but it is taking 10 hours to do...

I was wondering if it's safe to shut down and continue this at another time?

Cheers,
K.

Comment: Why not let it finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's safe in terms of you won't lose your existing working disk/plex but it's not smart as it's very likely it'll start rebuilding again - but it's up to you.